# Rails4 - Association has_many through - Reader_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, model-associations

I would like with Rails 4 to do a simple association beetween 3 models but i can't succeed to do that.

First model:Reader,Second model:Comments Third model : Books

The relation beetween the 3 models are:

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
    belongs_to :reader

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    has_many :books, through: :comments

I have no problem for the relation Book has_many :comments but i have some problem with the relation Reader has_many :comments.

Field from CommentsTable : username, message and reader_id (for the has_many association).
Field from ReaderTable : name , email.

I have a file _form.html.erb in view:

```
<%= form_for [@book, @comment] do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :book_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :reader_id, :placeholder => "reader id" %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
    <br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And an other file _comment.html.erb:

```
<% if comment.reader_id != nil %>
<li><strong><%= link_to comment.reader.name, comment.reader %></strong></li>
<p><%= comment.message %></p>
<% end %>
```

Like you see i have a form with reader_id and message. When the user will enter this 2 informations, it will appears the reader.name (thanks to reader_id) and the comment.message.
But i don't want that the user enter the integer "reader_id" (it has no sense) but directly the string "reader.name".
How can i do that, knowing that after i will do a link_to on the reader.name to comment.reader ?

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the reader is the user. If it is, then you'll probably want to have a whole authentication system (maybe think about Devise) and just assign the comment to the current user within the controller. You'll also want to assign the book in the controller.

EDIT:

Devise will make available a current_user method in your controller. So your create method in your comments controller should look like this:

```
def create
    comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
end
```

You don't need to assign the reader.name to comments. That's what the association is for. You can do comment.reader.name, or better yet, use delegate (look that up) and do comment.reader_name.

Comment: Yes i use Devise, the reader is exactly the user. But i don't know how can i assign a comment to the current user. My User table using with devise just have fields : email, id, password. It doesn't have a field "name" (for the comments). Moreover, i need to assign the reader.name to the comment because i need to create a relation beetween the reader_id and books via comment ( reader has_many :books, through: :comments)